# Uninstall silverlight in C# programmatically

Tags: windows, silverlight

I want to Uninstall silverlight in C# programmatically. can I get help regarding this. I need it for my project.

Comment: That is a little vague. Is this a debug build of Silverlight you wish to remove, or one of the various Silverlight browser plugins?

Comment: I would like to uninstall the silverlight runtime that is currently installed on the user machine, The one that appears in the Add/Remove Programs

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically uninstall any program, if it was installed via a Windows installer, using the [Windows Installer API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367449.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367449.aspx)

More information here too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367449.aspx